# White outline appearing when I convert to Png? (Using downloaded brush tool)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, brush

I want to use lightning bolts in one of my designs so downloaded a third party photoshop brush pack that allows you to easily place bolts. It look great on a blank (no background) canvas in the most recent version of Abobe photoshop but when I attempt to export to Png a thick white outline appears around all of the bolts and ruins the effect. I have tried this with 3 different lightning brush packs and it keeps happening. Below is a picture of the phenomenon, do you know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?[image: Bolts in PS]

[image: White outline]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a partially transparent glow. PNG-8 does not support partial transparency. All must be totally transparent or totally opaque.

As already written in other answers either

- remove the partial transparent part by selecting Matte = None or
- use PNG-24 format which supports partial transparency or
- discard the transparency and have a background. Then you can use JPG file format.

JPG saves space when compared to PNG-24 and gives smoother colors than PNG-8 if there's needed more than 256 colors.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, the Matte setting seemed to be the thing that was generating this outline. The default PNG setting for the matte is white setting the matte setting to 'None' and changing to PNG-24 the outline disappears and I get the desired result.

**Note that this only happened when I put the lightning bolts on a transparent background, if I used only solid color the outline from the matte would not be there. However I need a transparent background because I wanted to put this graphic on a shirt

[image]